# L5 - swagger why Required @SWG\Info() not found?

Tags: php, laravel-5, swagger

I'm integrating into my Laravel5 project swagger :

```
"darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^5.5"
```

I have two projects with no problem having the following block of code defined at the top of ../routes/api.php

```
/**
* @SWG\Swagger(
*   basePath="/api",
*   @SWG\Info(
*     title="MyApp API",
*     version="0.2"
*   )
* )
*/
```

Now with a new project I'm experiencing  @SWG\Info() not found error when :

```
 php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```

If I move the @SWG\Swagger block of code form routes\api.php to

```
 ..../app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php
```

Command l5-swagger:generate will instead succeed.

Why is that? Laravel Projects looks the same. What could prevent from generating the swagger having the SWG\info in routes\api.php?

Comment: In your l5-swagger config file (/config/l5-swagger.php), there you can find a key 'annotations' inside 'path' array which is set as base_path('app'). This means that all your annotations for swagger need to be inside your /app directory. You are free to choose file as per your structure and preference, but unless you change the config value, swagger will search for all annotations inside defined (/app) directory.

Answer (score 3):

You already installed this below the library.

```
"darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^5.5"
```

Then put this below code in parent controller below the class name like this.

```
/**
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 *   @SWG\Info(
 *     title="Site Title",
 *     version="1.0",
 *     description="Site description",
 *     @SWG\Contact(
 *         email="xyz@xyz.com"
 *     )
 *   )
 * )
 */
class Controller extends BaseController
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem as well.

Laravel version:5 5.7

After running command:

```
composer require zircote/swagger-php:2.*require zircote/swagger-php:2.*
```

Then add the following setting .env

```
SWAGGER_VERSION=2.0
```

Changing a line in Config/l5-swagger.php

```
'swagger_version' => env('SWAGGER_VERSION', '2.0'),
```

Problem solved~solved.